# Custom text screensaver

Tags: screensaver

Thinking about what would be useful to display in a screensaver, I realized that it would be nice to know how long the screensaver has been running. `gnome-screensaver-command --time` takes care of that. Now, how can I create a simple screensaver based on this value (plus perhaps some `ps` output), updating it at regular intervals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're technically inclined, you can actually write one without too much trouble!

Here's the [popsquares](http://svn.gnome.org/viewvc/gnome-screensaver/trunk/savers/popsquares.c?view=markup) source. Look how tiny it is!

GNOME Screensaver actually does support xscreensaver, so you can do this a few different ways :)

Here's a [guide](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/faq.html#writing-savers) for writing an xscreensaver, and some [examples](http://svn.gnome.org/viewvc/gnome-screensaver/trunk/savers/), as well as how they're [invoked](http://svn.gnome.org/viewvc/gnome-screensaver/trunk/src/gs-theme-manager.c?view=markup) by the screensaver it's self.

Here's a bit more from the GNOME [website](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeScreensaver/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#I_want_to_write_a_screensaver_theme.2C_how_do_I_do_that.3F).

I'd personally love this app! Perhaps someone could write it!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the Phosphor xscreensaver and just give it that for the input...

Comment: I know that I could search a bit to set it up, but could you please detail the steps to do so?